# PHP Crawler through an entire website

Tags: php, regex, web, fopen, web-crawler

I would like to retrieve articles and other contents from one website.
I get the idea of the crawler and suppose I can fopen distant pages and get text portions according to some regex or so.
What I wonder is how I can search not only through a single page (or pagination) but over the entire website, not having to run the crawler for each element, one by one and not forgetting any existing url in the process.

Note that I don't need this to be clean as it is a one time thing.
The web agency I have a contract with wants to charge me a huge amount of money for a dump of my own database and there is no way around it so I have to find a quick workaround.
Can you walk me through this in order to get me started?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You could determine the pages on their site by the sitemap but this isn't the most reliable solution as the pages may not be on their site map. The best way IMO would be to use a recursive function to gather the data, starting from the home page finding all site specific links using a regular expression on the retrieved data until you have crawled as many links as you can. This will have a spider web effect and pull a large amount of data.

We currently have a similar implementation to take about 5,000 pages of data from a badly built API system.

Comment: The thing is I don't need a large amount of data, I need the whole data, not missing anything, with a 100% certainty

Comment: Unfortunately there is no really way of getting every page with 100% certainty - if there are no references to a file it would be very hard to find - especially automatically!

Comment: For example javascript added.

Comment: Thank you Chris. Well I have to find a way or pay a thousand euros for a 5 Mo dump of data that are my own property...

Comment: @Flash thunder: what do you mean?

Comment: @Baylock: I mean that many sites have antispam javascript based solution, that won't be detected by PHP at all. They are creating links / content via javascript.

Comment: Given the circumstance you would likely find the best solution would be to use the wget method suggested by @FlashThunder You can then filter through the individual files using a script - it is by no means an easy task though!

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to not to do it without fetching all links site by site. Even when using some third party scripts, they will always have to send at least as many http requests as it has to.

The easiest way to do this is to use wget with -r parameter, it will download whole site and then search given regex in downloaded files.

Comment: wget will get me files and I don't need files, I need to sort and filter what I fetch (text only) and store it in the new database. I already used a site sucker software but then I'm back to square one as I still have to figure out how to get and sort the data from all the downloaded files.

Comment: To refine my answer, my point is to redo my website on a new server as I want to leave the web agency that is taking me hostage. So my point is not tho retrieve the data on my desktop but to collect the raw data, sort it, filter it and eventually recreate a new database for the new website. With this in mind, I don't think we have a winner with wget.